# Authorize.net Hosted Payment form prefill address and email information

Tags: php, authorize.net

I have a two part form. Part one requests email address, physical address. Part two once submitted, the data looks like this:

```
[name_first] => John
[name_last] => Doe
[email] => test@test.com
[invoice] => 12345
[price] => 35
[address_street address] => PO Box 123
[address_address line 2] => 
[address_city] => Anytown
[address_state] => NY
[address_zip] => 12345
[address_country] => USA
```

I want to then prefill the address and invoice number to the Hosted Payment Form so that the visitor doesn't have to fill it in twice. I'm using the Auth.net sample code to generate the token and can see where I pass on the payment amount, but how do I pass through the other in data to generate the form?

```
<?php
      require dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php';
      use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
      use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
      use net\authorize\api\constants as ANetEnvironment;

      define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");

      function getAnAcceptPaymentPage($values = array())
      {
        // Common setup for API credentials
        $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
        $merchantAuthentication->setName('5KP3u95bQpv');
        $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("xxxxxxxx");

        //create a transaction
        $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
        $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
        $transactionRequestType->setAmount($values['price']);

        echo '<P> :: ' . $transactionRequestType->getCustomer() . '</p>';

        // Set Hosted Form options
        $setting1 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
        $setting1->setSettingName("hostedPaymentButtonOptions");
        $setting1->setSettingValue("{\"text\": \"Pay\"}");

        $setting2 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
        $setting2->setSettingName("hostedPaymentOrderOptions");
        $setting2->setSettingValue("{\"show\": true}");

        $setting3 = new AnetAPI\SettingType();
        $setting3->setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
        $setting3->setSettingValue("{\"url\": \"$values[receipt_url]\", \"cancelUrl\": \"$values[cancel_url]\", \"showReceipt\": true}");

        // Build transaction request
        $request = new AnetAPI\GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();
        $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
        $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

        $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting1);
        $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting2);
        $request->addToHostedPaymentSettings($setting3);

        //execute request
        $controller = new AnetController\GetHostedPaymentPageController($request);
        $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

        if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok") )
        {
          return $response->getToken()."\n";
         }
        else
        {
          echo "ERROR :  Failed to get hosted payment page token\n";
          $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
          echo "RESPONSE : " . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . "  " .$errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";
        }
        return $response;
      }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you request the token, include anything you would like to be pre-populated in the "transactionRequest" element of the request.

```
 "transactionRequest": {
                "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
                "amount": "25.00",
                "customer": {
                    "email": "customer@email.com"
                },
                "billTo": {
                    "firstName": "John",
                    "lastName": "Jones",
                    "company": "Microsoft",
                    "address": "100 Sunrise Way",
                    "city": "Palm Springs",
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": "92234",
                    "country": "USA"
                }
```

By the way, I hope that is not your real Transaction Key. If it is you should change it.

Comment: It's the test I'd that auth.net includes in their sample code